# Google Compute Engine Network Internal DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a CoreOS cluster on GCE and trying to get the cloud-init going with my own DNS entries. The DNS is being set up in a Google Cloud DNS zone but it appears that this DNS zone is not being used by the Network that was set up.

With AWS you can associate a DNS zone with a VPC, is it possible to do the same with Google Cloud?

Comment: Did you update your domain name servers? If you are using a third-party domain name registrar, you will need to update your domain's name servers to use Cloud DNS. Please visit this [article](https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers).

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, you can provide further information as Kamran suggested to further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested previously by Kamran, if you are using third-party name registrar, you will need to update your domain's name servers to use Cloud DNS. For more information on how to do this, see this updating your domain's name servers [guide](https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers).

Additionally, you can retrieve the list of name servers that are configured to serve DNS queries for your zone by running `gcloud dns managed-zones describe [EXAMPLE_ZONE]` command as indicated in this Look up your Cloud DNS name servers [section](https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers#look_up_your_product_name_short_name_servers).

Comment: I feel that this answer is not relevant. The question seems to be about using the DNS servers from Cloud DNS in the OS, instead of the default one that also handles the meta data. This has nothing to do with domain registrars.